# HttpClient post hangs on timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code;

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    PreAuthenticate = false,
};
var webclient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
webclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
webclient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1);

var res = webclient.PostAsync("http://localhost/test", "'test'", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result; //.ContinueWith(x => ProcessResult(x));
```

The .Result blocks the thread and hangs the application.  If I replace it with the continuation, it is never executed.

If I increase the timeout, the code works, so it seems to be the failing timeout.

I've solved it by using another task to timeout but would like to understand better;

```
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20))) == task)
{
    //success
}
else
{
     //failure
}
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18231104/1768303

Comment: I've realised this is due to exceptions.  If I hook into the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event I can see the exceptions that are being raised.

Comment: Noseratio - the question is similiar.  However, I don't want to know how to set the timeout but why it is hanging and never entering the continuewith.  Also, a get will never hang - it will raise a task cancelled exception.  The post just hangs.

Comment: I think you're hitting a bug in HttpClient.  It loses any exception thrown when it is uploading content on a post and the task hangs.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547814/why-cant-i-catch-exception-from-httpclient-sendasync-when-using-objectcontent.  This was fixed in the latest release of the nuget package which will help on .Net 4.0, Phone, and Silverlight, but you'll need to wait for the next version of .Net 4.5.* where HttpClient is part of .Net.